# How to separate flat file of unspaced characters into numbers?l

Tags: excel, vba

I need to separate numbers using array in Excel.

For example,

> 0987787634366787667867112327776678

To be separated in groups of 8, 6, 8, 8, 4.

So the result in every cell will be

> 09877876 | 343667 | 87667867 | 11232777 | 6678

Comment: If you treat the long number as a string, you can simply put these functions in five columns to get your substring numbers.
`=LEFT(A1;8)`, `=MID(A1; 9; 6)`, `=MID(A1; 15; 8)`, `=MID(A1; 23; 8)`, `=RIGHT(A1; 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strWhole As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String, str4 As String, str5 As String
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop column A from row 2 to lastrow
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            strWhole = "'" & .Range("A" & i).Value
            str1 = "'" & Left(strWhole, 8)
            str2 = "'" & Mid(strWhole, 9, 6)
            str3 = "'" & Mid(strWhole, 15, 8)
            str4 = "'" & Mid(strWhole, 23, 8)
            str5 = "'" & Right(strWhole, 4) + "."

            .Range("B" & i).Value = str1
            .Range("C" & i).Value = str2
            .Range("D" & i).Value = str3
            .Range("E" & i).Value = str4
            .Range("F" & i).Value = str5

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```